# Scattering amplitude with Born series

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, approximations, scattering-cross-section

[image][image]

I didn't understand the step before similar sign in the image u can refer image for more elaboration.

Comment: Just define $\hat r=\vec r/|\vec r|=\vec r/r$ and do an Taylor expansion in $|\vec r'|/r$.

Comment: Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but *type it out instead* so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead. Similarly, quoting text without referencing its source is **never** appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{1}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}\prime|} = (r^2 + r'^2 - 2\vec{r} \cdot \vec{r}')^{-1/2} \approx \frac{1}{r}(1 - 2\frac{\vec{r} \cdot \vec{r}\prime}{r^2})^{-1/2} \approx \frac{1}{r}(1 + \frac{\vec{r} \cdot \vec{r}\prime}{r^2}) \approx \frac{1}{r}$

This is expanding the dot product and using the binomial approximation $(1 + x)^{p} \approx 1 + px$ for $x \propto \frac{r\prime}{r} \ll 1$.